# Creating arguments which are evenly distributed in $[0,\pi)$

Tags: python, distribution

I want to create arguments ${ \psi_{m}}$ which are evenly distributed in $[0,\pi)$ in python where $m=1,...,M$ with $M=100$. I would be appreciate if someone could help me that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not very understandable. What have you tried ? What is your input ? What is your desired output ?

Comment: Do you want *random* values from your interval, or *evenly distributed* values (e.g. `0.1`, `0.2`, `0.3`, etc.)? Are you using a numerical library like `numpy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to sample 100 numbers that are evenly distributed in the range `[0, pi)`, then you can use:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.uniform(0.0, np.pi, size=100)
```

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Can I ask another question which is related to my question above?

Comment: I want to define vectors $q_m =(q_{m1},q_{m,2})$ in which $q_{m,1}=cos(\psi_m )$ and $q_{m,2}=sin(psi_m )$ with $m=1,...,300$. I was wondring if you could help me about that. Thanks very much.

Comment: I'm glad to help, but please make another question and post link here. Stack Overflow only allows a single question per post :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't ask another question because of this comment: You can’t post new questions right now (You can’t post new questions right now
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from your account because most of your questions need improvement or are out of scope for this site) :(

Comment: Seems like there is a cooldown. So in your case, use: `d=np.random.uniform(0.0, np.pi, size=300)` then  `data = np.array([np.cos(d), np.sin(d)])`